# How to suppress the link border around an image?

Tags: asp.net, css

I am trying to use a pencil icon for a link which will lead to an edit screen in ASP.NET.  When I do this (String.Form supplies relevant values to the QueryString):

```
<a href="ViewEditARContact.aspx?userid={0}&agency={1}"><img src="../Images/icon-pencil.gif" alt="Edit" /></a>
```

I get a blue (or maroon) border around the image:

[image]

I would like to suppress this border.  I have found that these

```
style="text-decoration: none;"
style="border-style: none;"
```

don't do it. Is there a way to suppress this border or am I stuck with it?

**Edited to Add:**

@DA's answer provided the clue, which was to set the border to none in the image, instead of the anchor (link).  As per:

```
<a href="ViewEditARContact.aspx?userid={0}&agency={1}"><img src="../Images/icon-pencil.gif" alt="Edit" style="border: none;" /></a>
```

Comment: How about `border: 0; outline: 0;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it a border of zero or none:

```
a img {border: none}
```

Comment: That's the clue I needed to set the border on the right element to do the job.  Thanks!